# Random Point on Edge of Cylinder

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, random

How can I get a random point on just the curved edge of a cylinder?

```
c = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 2];
RandomPoint[RegionBoundary[c], 50]
```

almost works, but also adds points to the top and bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You could intersect the boundary of an elongated cylinder with a cuboid:

```
region = RegionIntersection[
    Cuboid[{-2,-2,0}, {2,2,2}],
    RegionBoundary @ Cylinder[{{0,0,-1},{0,0,3}},2]
];
```

This creates a region consisting of the curved boundary of a cylinder along the $z$-axis of radius 2 and length 2. Then, use [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint) to get your points:

```
pts = RandomPoint[region, 1000];
```

Visualization:

```
Graphics3D[Point[pts]]
```

[image]

You could also intersect the boundary of the desired cylinder with an elongated cylinder:

```
region = RegionIntersection[
    RegionBoundary @ Cylinder[{{0,0,-1}, {0,0,3}}, 2],
    RegionBoundary @ Cylinder[{{0,0,0}, {0,0,2}},2]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cylinderHeight = 5;
cylinderRadius = 4;
myTheta = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}];
myHeight = RandomReal[];
{cylinderRadius Cos[myTheta], cylinderRadius Sin[myTheta], cylinderHeight myHeight}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pr[r_, h_] := ParametricRegion[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], z}, {{θ, 0, 2 π}, {z, 0, h}}];

Graphics3D[{Point[RandomPoint[pr[2, 1], 1000]], Opacity[.5, Yellow], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 2]}]
```

[image]